# Trying to iterate through Class[ ] comparing using instanceof

Tags: java, instanceof

I'm trying to iterate through an array of `Class` to determine if candidate object is 'interesting'. `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` don't have an appropriate parent class (they are siblings, but the not all siblings are interesting). I can't add a parent class nor can I modify A, B, C, D. I want to do something like the below, but the syntax isn't legal.

```
private static final Class[] types = { A.class, B.class, C.class, D.class};
....
void method(Object cand) {
    for (Class c : types) {
        if (cand instanceof c) {//cand is interesting, but c isn't type
             ( (c) cand).methodInInterestingClasses();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nit: don't use raw types. Use a `List<Class<?>>` instead of a `Class[]`.

Comment: Agreed. Went for fastest to type demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the `instanceof` with the name of a type, known at compile-time.

You can fix the first part using the [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
if (c.isInstance(cand))
```

... but that's not going to help you with `methodInInterestingClasses()`, which it sounds like you'll have to call with reflection.

Comment: Thanks, ended up using reflection.